# Apply multiple styles in one cell in Aspose-Cells

Tags: java, excel, aspose-cells

I want to add multiple styles in one cell.

EX: **I** *Want* ***Some*** Help

Now I dont have the full text at a time. I only have a chunk at a time (Like, "I", "Want", "Some", "Help" and associated style) . But I need to set the whole string formatted in one cell.

How can I do that with Aspose.cells and Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get FontSetting object for the selected characters, and then change the style. Article Reference from Aspose documentation is http://goo.gl/GhtDDy

**EDIT**
setValue() method in the API will set the complete value. In your case, you have chunks with associated styles. Ideally, there should be method like appendValue(String, Style), but such method does not exist in the Aspose.Cells library. Please request this feature in [Aspose forums](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx).

Check the below method, you can have limited style, only font setting applied in your scenario, with the current API.

I assume that you have an array list of strings (chunks of values) and an array list of styles (associated styles for each chunk). Separator character can be a space.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // Instantiating a Workbook object
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

    // Accessing the added worksheet in the Excel file
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Style> styles = new ArrayList<Style>();

    // Separator character
    String separator = " ";

    // I
    values.add("I");
    styles.add(new Style()); styles.get(0).getFont().setBold(true);
    // Want
    values.add("Want");
    styles.add(new Style()); styles.get(1).getFont().setBold(false);
    // Some
    values.add("Some");
    styles.add(new Style()); styles.get(2).getFont().setBold(true);
    // Help
    values.add("Help");
    styles.add(new Style()); styles.get(3).getFont().setBold(false);

    // Get cell A1
    Cell cell = cells.get("A1");

    appendValuesWithStyles(cell, values, styles, separator);

    workbook.save(Common.DATA_DIR + "cellstyle.xlsx");
}

private static void appendValuesWithStyles(Cell cell, ArrayList<String> values, ArrayList<Style> styles, String separator)
{
    // Lets combine all chunks, because we can only use setValue()
    String allCharacters = "";
    // First set the whole value in cell
    int iValue = 0;
    for (String value : values)
    {
        allCharacters = allCharacters + value;
        if (iValue < values.size())
            allCharacters = allCharacters + separator;

        iValue++;
    }

    // Set the value once
    cell.setValue(allCharacters);

    // Now set the styles
    int startIndex = 0, valueLength = 0;
    for (int iStyle = 0 ; iStyle < styles.size() ; iStyle++)
    {
        // Get the associated value and the style.
        String value = values.get(iStyle);
        Style style = styles.get(iStyle);

        // We need the start character and length of string to set the style
        valueLength = value.length();

        cell.characters(startIndex, valueLength).getFont().setBold(style.getFont().isBold());

        // Increment the start index
        startIndex = startIndex + valueLength + separator.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I stated before I can't get a full text at a time. I only get a chunk. So it would be great if I can **Append** string ( Cause setValue replace previous value ) with the stylesheet applied.

Comment: I have edited the answer, see if you can use the solution somehow. With the current API of Aspose.Cells, this is only a workaround.